# Volume by Cylindrical Method vs. Slicing

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, volume

I have to calculate an integral, from which I am using the method Slicing, and Cylindrical Shells.  I was thus rotating it by the x-axis.

I am using the functions $x=\frac{y}{4}$, and $x=\sqrt{y}$

I did it using slicing, and get this integral, and the answer.

$$V_1=\pi\int_\limits{0}^{4}((4x)^2-(x^2)^2)dx$$
This is then later equal to $V_1=\frac{2048}{15}\pi$
Then using cylindrical Shells method to get the answer:

$$V_2=2\pi\int_\limits{0}^{16}(y(\frac{y}{4}-\sqrt{y}))dy$$
And it does not equal the same $V_1$.
How does one do it using cylindrical shells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have set up the integral for the washer method is correct. However, the integral for the shell method (or *the cylindrical shell method* as it's also called) is slightly wrong. It should be the following:

$$
V_2=2\pi\int_{0}^{16}\bigg[y\left(\sqrt{y}-\frac{y}{4}\right)\bigg]\,dy=
2\pi\bigg[\frac{2}{5}y^{5/2}-\frac{1}{12}y^3\bigg]_{0}^{16}=
\frac{2048\pi}{15}
$$

You should be subtracting $\frac{y}{4}$ from $\sqrt{y}$ because $\sqrt{y}$ lies to the right of $\frac{y}{4}$ or above it if you rotate the entire coordinate system 90° to the right and then flip it so that it looks like x and y have exchanged placed.

Wolfram Alpha gives [the same answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%202*pi%20*x*(sqrt(x)-x%2F4)%20dx%20from%200%20to%2016).

Answer (score 2):

If you evaluate your second integral accurately, the result (multiplying by $2\pi$) comes to 
$-\frac{2048}{15}\pi$.
The reason it is different from the other result is you subtracted the larger value of $y$ from the smaller value of $y.$
You should subtract the smaller value from the larger one.

Answer (score 1):

over the interval $[0,16], \frac {y}{4} < \sqrt y$

You have the sign backwards.

$2\pi \int_0^{16} y(y^{\frac 12}- \frac{y}{4})\ dy\\
2\pi \int_0^{16} y^{\frac 32}- \frac{y^2}{4})\ dy\\
2\pi(\frac {2}{5} y^{\frac 52}- \frac {y^3}{12})|_0^{16}\\
2\pi(4^5)(\frac 1{15})$

And washers:

$\pi\int_0^4 16 x^2 - x^4\ dx\\
\pi(\frac {16x^3}{3} - \frac {x^4}{5})|_0^4\\
\pi(4^5)(\frac 2{15})$